# Fastest way to get path from string

Tags: php

I got a list of strings like this:

- `/my/path/to/file.txt`
- `/another/path/to/another/file.jpg`

Now I would like to use https://github.com/Ne-Lexa/php-zip#Documentation-Open-Zip-Archive to add files to a Zip archive.

Well - this library does not create the folders in the zip automatically, so I would need to check:

- What is the path of `/my/path/to/file.txt`? (-> `/my/path/to`)
- Does the path exist in the zip?
- If not: create it
- Add file to zip

At the moment I solved this by doing

```
private function archiveFile( $file )
{
    $path = pathinfo($path);
    $path = $path['dirname'];

    if(!isset($this->zip[$path])){
        $this->zip->addDirRecursive($path);
    }

    $this->zip->addFile( $file, $path );

    return true;
}
```

As I am doing this with a lot of files, I would need to have a really fast method to archive this.

Comment: What's the main question? Where've you been stuck on? Otherwise `pathinfo` plus `is_dir`...

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question: I would like to know, which is the fastest way to do that, because I am doing this with a lot of files.

Comment: If you've faced with performance issues, better to avoid using custom libraries and take the basic `ZipArchive` class (http://php.net/manual/ru/class.ziparchive.php). In that case `addFile` will automatically create required subfolders.